# moving content db for a site collection to another db server

Tags: content-database, database-server

Is it possible to move a content database from one db server to another db server? I read an an article stating it's not possible you can move contend db within the same database server. Can anyone please shed some light on this?

```
Move-SPSite
```

This is from [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825328%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

> The source content database and destination content database must be
>   located on the same instance of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps you will need to take
Lets call content DB "MyTESTContentDB"

1. Do a database backup for the content db "MyTESTContentDB" from sql management studio
2. Go to target DB Server and create a empty database naming "MyTESTContentDB" after the content DB
3. Restore the backup from step 1 to empty database create in step 2 "MyTESTContentDB"
4. Go to SharePoint server and run following script
   Dismount-spcontentdatabase "MyTESTContentDB" and type "Y" to confirm
5. Run the following script

   stsadm -o addcontentdb -url http://intranet.company.com/mytestsite -databasename MyTESTContentDB -databaseserver TARGETDBSERVER

You will have to input actual URL, actual db name and correct target db server name

Comment: PERFECT. Took me few minutes to follow all the steps. Thank you for detailed steps.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

1) Add a new Content Database to your existing web application, but with the database pointing to the new SQL server.  You can use the New-SPContentDatabase Cmdlet to do this and specify the server at the same time: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607572.aspx.

2) Use the Move-SPSite Cmdlet to move the desired site collections from the existing content database to the new one.

Comment: I can't do that. There are 30 other sites on the web applications that will stay with the old database server.

Comment: You can only move things that the Site Collection level.  Using the Move-SPSite cmdlet will allow you to move single site collections from one content database to the other without impacting other site collections.  If you are looking at moving certain sites within a site collection, you would need to export the SPWeb and import it to your new location (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for pitching in. Moe's Solution worked like charm. Thanks both of you.